# Print a vector of doubles to file in parallel (C++, OpenMP)

Tags: c++, file, openmp

I am trying to output a big vector of doubles in parallel using OpenMP. Currently I have concluded to this:

```
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <omp.h>
 #include <fstream>

 int main()
 {
    int n = 10000000;
    double* v = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v[i] = (double)i;

    int chunk;

    std::ofstream filestream;
    filestream.open("file", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    double tic = omp_get_wtime(), toc;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();

        if (id == 0) chunk = n / omp_get_num_threads(); //todo: assert that 4 threads have been set

        double* vsub;
        int start = id * chunk;
        int end = (id + 1) * chunk - 1;

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            std::cout << "Id = " << id << ", Chunk = " << chunk << ", start = " << start << ", end = " << end << '\n';
            vsub = v + start;
        }

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed;
        for (int i = 0; i < end - start + 1; i++)
        {
            ss << vsub[i] << '\n';
        }
        std::string s = ss.str();

        #pragma omp for ordered schedule(static, 1)
        for (int t = 0; t < omp_get_num_threads(); ++t)
        {
        #pragma omp ordered
            {
                filestream.write(s.c_str(), s.size());
            }
        }
    }

    toc = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("It took %f seconds to run\n", toc - tic);
    getchar();

    delete[] v;
    filestream.close();
 }
```

Using 1 thread the time to run in my desktop is about 7.3 sec while using 4 is 4.0 sec. I am aware that using a buffer of char instead of stringstream the speed will improve, but I am thinking why this code does not scale fine. By the way, 95% of the time is spent to construct the strings rather than writing to the file.

Comment: The output itself, both to `std::cout` and to the file, will need synchronization between the threads to make sure that only one thread at a time does it. This bottleneck will become worse as there are more threads.

Comment: but 95% of the time is spent to construct the strings where there is no need for synchronization between the threads.

Comment: The memory allocations when you create strings also need synchronization.

Comment: I tried with char buffers (one for each thread) but the behaviour did not change. Thus memory allocations for strings might not be the problem.

Comment: You have a bug when (n%4) != 0...

Comment: I am aware of this "bug", it can be fixed by using a scheduled for loop when constructing the stringstreams